# What I'm missing to create a Collection View with a CollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I don't know why my collection is not displaying any cell.
I will write the steps I use to create the most simple Collection View using a UICollectionViewController.

1. I delete the default View Controller Scene in Storyboard.
2. I add a Collection View Controller as well as a Collection View inside.
3. I select the Collection View Controller in Storyboard and I set the background color as white and I check the option *Is initial View Controller*.
4. I set the cell identifier as *Cell*.
5. I add a new Cocoa Touch Class file subclass of *UICollectionViewController*.
6. In CollectionViewController, I set `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` o return `1` and `numberOfItemsInSection` to return `2`.
7. Also, in CollectionViewController, inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I add `cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor`

After this I run the app and I see the white background of the Collection View, but no cells.

Also, I've tried deleting the line

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

in `ViewDidLoad` because I read it in an answer to other question on this site.

If I understand why it is not working, I think I will understand why it is not working in an app I'm trying to write.

Comment: Why do you have to add a new UICollectionView? The UICollectionViewController comes with a UICollection as its default view.

Comment: Thanks, @Rage. I didn't know that. However, it doesn't seem to be the reason why it is not showing. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your view controller in the storyboard and select the Identity Inspector in the Utilities menu on the right. In the class field there type in the name of the UICollectionViewController subclass you created.

Secondly, if you have added a separate UICollectionView, select it in the storyboard. Go to connections Inspector and connect its delegate and datasource to your view controller.